# Hilt Instrumentation test with Workmanager not working

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-workmanager, android-instrumentation, dagger-hilt

When I try to run an ActivityScenario in my application that contains a WorkManager I get the following error on start:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
```

Using the `WorkManagerTestInitHelper` from the `work-test` artifact doesnt help either.

The WorkManager is defined like this:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideWorkmanager(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
```

This is my test atm:

```
    @HiltAndroidTest
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
    class LoginTest {
    
        @get:Rule(order = 0)
        var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    
        @get:Rule(order = 1)
        val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)
    
        @Before
        fun before() {
            val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
            val config = Configuration.Builder()
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
                .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
                .build()
            WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
        }
    
        @Test
        fun test() {
            ...
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `@get:Rule` executes before the `@Before` does, as per the [Google Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-rules#activity-test-rule):

> This rule provides functional testing of a single activity. The activity under test is launched before each test annotated with @Test and before any method annotated with @Before. It's terminated after the test is completed and all methods annotated with @After are finished. To access the activity under test in your test logic, provide a callback runnable to ActivityScenarioRule.getScenario().onActivity().

In order to fix this, you would need to initialise the `WorkManager` in the test with `WorkManagerTestInitHelper` **before** you try to launch the activity.

To do this, you should avoid using `ActivityScenarioRule` and use `ActivityScenario` instead, you can do something like this:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginTest {
    private lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun before() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        val config = Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
            .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
            .build()
        WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)

        scenario = launchActivity()
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED).onActivity { 
             activity -> // do some test with the activity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I had similar problems trying to instrument with Hilt - the app would start running on its own merry way before my `@Before` was even finished - this appears to have solved my issue. Thank you! `launchActivity()` should be `ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)` (or whatever activity you want to launch

Answer (score 2):

To take advantage of `ActivitScenarioRule` and ensure that the `WorkManager` is initialized first I created a custom JUnit rule.

```
class WorkManagerRule : TestRule {
override fun apply(base: Statement?, description: Description?): Statement {
    return object : Statement() {
        override fun evaluate() {
            val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
            val config = Configuration.Builder()
                .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
                .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
                .build()
            WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
            try {
                base?.evaluate()
            } finally {
                Log.d("WorkManagerRule", "Do some teardown")
            }
        }

    }
}


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class MyTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    var workMgrRule = WorkManagerRule()

    @get:Rule(order = 2)
    var activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    //Your test code here...
}
```

I used the instructions for creating JUnit rules found [here](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/writing-your-own-junit-rule-3df41997b10c).

Comment: very nice! thanks!